# How do pause everything for a specific amount of time in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So I have this code:

```
if (ball.position.x < 45) {
    ball.position = ccp(200, 200);
    score1 = score1 + 1;
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score %d - %d", score1, score2]];
}
```

and in the Main init method I have this:

```
[self schedule:@selector(move) interval:.01];
```

Which just moves the ball around the screen. I was wondering how I would pause for lets say 3 seconds, between moving the ball to its new position and resuming the movement off the ball. (and for the record the first bit of code is inside the move method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post what the resume movement method is? To stop the ball movement you need to unschedule `[self unschedule:@selector(move:)]` You could run the resume movement method after a delay `[self performSelector:@selector(resume) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f]` you could also do the delay with `CCCallFunc` like this:

```
id moveCallFunc = [CCCallFunc ActionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myMove)];
id resumeCallFunc = [CCCallFunc ActionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(resume)];
id tDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3.0f];

[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:moveCallFunc, tDelay, resumeCallFunc, nil]];
```

If your move and resume functions are to be scheduled like you did above you can wrap the schedule methods so you can use them as selectors like:

```
-(void)myMove {

   [self schedule:@selector(move:)];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After, if statement is true, you may  `[self unschedule:_cmd];` then  `[self schedule:@selector(newPos) interval:3];` and assign in the **newPos** method a new position to the ball.